# ieee floating point format

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I'm having trouble converting 19861119 into ieee floating point format (single precision).  I hope someone can tell me where I've lost my way.

In binary, the value is `b1:00101111:00001110:01111111` (using : to mark every 8 bits from the rhs), which is `b1.00101111:00001110:01111111 * 2^24`.  So the float is `b00101111:00001110:01111111` and the biased exponent is `24 + 127 = 151 = b10010111`.  The float is 24 bits long but ieee format only allows 23 bits for it, which looks problematic to me.  Does the format lack sufficient precision to store a yyyymmdd date?

When I write the output from Python's `struct.pack("f", 19861119)` to file and take a look with a hex editor, I see `x4087974b`.  After allowing for little-endianness this is `x4b978740`.  So Python has written a biased exponent of `b01010111 = 87` and a float of `b0010111:10000111:01000000` which bear little resemblance to any of the numbers I calculated. What have I missed?

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Answer (score 1):

The number is stored **rounded**: 19861120 becomes 0x4B978740. The unrounded value is 0x4B97873F.

Here's 0x4B978740 in binary:

```
0   10010111   [1]   0010111 10000111 01000000

+   127 + 24    1                   ~ .1838150
```

And 2<sup>24</sup> = 16777216.

The [online float calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html) is great for exploring such details.

Talking about rounding modes in IEE754 could fill a whole essay...

Answer (score 1):

The original number is:

```
1 0010 1111 0000 1110 0111 1111
```

Normalizing we have:

```
1,0010 1111 0000 1110 0111 1111 x 2²⁴
```

Since only 23 bits of the fractional part will be stored:

```
  1,0010 1111 0000 1110 0111 111 x 2²⁴
                              +1 (if rounded)
= 1,0010 1111 0000 1110 1000 000 x 2²⁴

= 0|100 1011 1|001 0111 1000 0111 0100 0000
  s    exp         23 bit fractional part
= 0x4B978740
```

And if I understood well, that's what are you getting.

Answer (score 1):

32 bit single-precision does not have enough precision to store `YYYYMMDD` dates. Let's say we go up to 20 million, which is 25 bits. So you always lose one bit.

The one thing to keep in mind with floating-point formats is that in the mantissa part, the first digit is always 1. Single and double precision take advantage of that by not storing it.

In your notation: `19861119 = +1 * b1.00101111:00001110:01111111 * 2^24`

So, for the three parts of the number, we have:

1. The sign is 0.
2. The exponent part is 127 + 24 = 151 = b1001011:1
3. The mantissa part is the first 23 bits after the initial zero, rounded to even: `0010111:10000111:01000000

So the full number is:

```
0 1001011:1 0010111:10000111:01000000
s eeeeeee e mmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm
```

or in hex, depending on ended-ness: `4b978740` / `4087974b`.